# Python - Ensuring that event notifications are not sent before a pre specified time

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python code in which I'd want to send a notification to a user when a specific condition is met. The event can occur every second and I do not want to send notifications every second.

How do I program (pseudo code probably) so that my notifications are sent every 30 minutes, even if event continues to occur more frequently?

Comment: Do you have any code started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to specify what you want to do more precisely, e.g., will you notify the user after the first event, but then not again for 30 minutes? Or wait for 30 minutes after the first event, and then notify the user of all events in the previous 30 minutes? Or notify the user at 0 and 30 minutes past the hour if there were any events during the prior 30 minutes?

I'll assume that your code (in another thread) will call event_occurred() whenever an event happens, and that calling notify() will inform the user.

Here is code that would notify the user on the 30 minute mark about any events that occurred during the prior 30 minutes:

```
import time, threading

interval = 30 * 60
counter_lock = threading.Lock()

n_events = 0

# record an event (called from another thread)
def event_occurred():
    with counter_lock:
        n_events += 1

# wake every 30 minutes and report the number of events
while True:
    with counter_lock:
        if n_events > 0:
            notify()
            n_events = 0
    # wait for next reporting time
    sleep(interval - (time.time() % interval))
```

Here is code that will notify the user right away about the first event and then wait at least 30 minutes before notifying about any other events (note: this will terminate when your main code does):

```
import time, threading

interval = 30 * 60
counter_lock = threading.Lock()
thread_lock = threading.Lock()

n_events = 0
waiting_thread = None

# record an event (called from another thread)
def event_occurred():
    # increment the event counter
    with counter_lock:
        n_events += 1
    with thread_lock:
        if not waiting_thread:
            # this is the first event in the last 30 minutes
            # report the event
            notify()
            n_events = 0
            # wait at least 30 minutes before reporting any more events
            waiting_thread = threading.Timer(interval, report_status)
            # make sure the thread closes automatically when the main program ends
            waiting_thread.daemon = True   


# at the end of 30 minutes, report any events that have occurred
def report_status():
    # clear the waiting thread
    with thread_lock:
        waiting_thread = None
    # report the events, if any
    with counter_lock:
        if n_events > 0:
            notify()
            n_events = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you man for sharing the code. I'll try to implement.

Actually I am trying to create an aquarium controller that'd eventually take care of lot of tasks for me. Right now, I am using a raspberry pi, along with few temperature sensors, to measure my tank temperature.  As long as the temperature goes beyond say 28 degrees, I plan to trigger few actions. Right now it's just an email notification.

The code I am using is simply comparing the temperature and nothing much.